# Textures under OSX

Tags: mac

I use Textures 2.2.0.18 under Mac OSX 10.6.8. Works perfectly.

My question is: is anyone using Textures under more advanced versions of OSX,
for instance 7 or 8?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this really off-topic? (Genuinely asking)

Comment: This is absolutely *not* off topic.

Answer (score 1):

The [BlueSky website](http://blueskytex.com) says:

> A typical LaTeX document of 30 pages takes less than a tenth of a second to compile on a 5-year-old MacBook under OSX10.10, a book of 400 pages less than half a second.

Which implies, that `Textures` works with a recent version of OS X, i.e. 10.10 (Yosemite).